# Issue with toggle-topbar in foundation zurb

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

When i resize my page, i get the toggle-topbar text, but it doesn't display the menu when i click on it.

This is my code :

This is the include i do (i use CodeIgniter at the same time and the files are well included) :

```
 <!-- CSS FILES -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php print base_url("assets/css"); ?>/header.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php print base_url("assets/css"); ?>/app.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php print base_url("assets/css"); ?>/content.css">


  <!-- JS FILES -->
  <script src="<?php print base_url("assets/plugin/foundation/js/vendor/"); ?>/custom.modernizr.js"></script>
```

And this is my top-bar :

```
</head>
<body>
<div class="fixed">
    <nav class="top-bar">
        <ul class="title-area">
        <li class="name">
            <a href="<?php site_url(); ?>"><img src="<?php print base_url("/assets/img"); ?>/logo_header.png" class="logo_header"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
    </ul>

    <section class="top-bar-section">
  <!-- Right Nav Section -->
        <ul class="right">
            <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php print base_url("/assets/img"); ?>/connexion_button.png"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php print base_url("/assets/img"); ?>/register_button.png" class="header_button"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</nav>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I use Foundation Zurb 4.3.1. Where am i wrong ?

Comment: What about a fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Did you include the foundation.css ?

Comment: We've experienced this as well.  In our case, just refreshing the page works most of the time.  It seems the browser isn't "refreshing" just by resizing the window.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly was the same issue with me, following are the steps that helped me resolving the issue:

1. [Re-Downloaded updated Complete Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/develop/download.html).
2. Included html meta(viewport) tag that I was missing earlier.
3. I'm including the files at my page in this way:

   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/foundation/foundation.css"/>`

    `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/foundation/app.css"/>`

     `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>`
   `<script src="/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>`
   `<script src="/js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>`
   `<script src="/js/foundation/foundation.topbar.js"></script>`
4. Called Foundation function in jquery rather than js as below:
   `<script>`
   `$(document).ready(function() {`
   `$(document).foundation();`
   `});`
   `</script>`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I edited my answer by mentioning the steps that helped me resolving the issue, hopefully it will help others also.